# How can I set my index.html when it's inside a folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Very new to AWS S3 Console. I have an app that has been uploaded and placed inside a bucket. All the files in the app were uploaded inside a 'webApp' folder, including my index.html that has been set as my index document.

I get a '404' Error when loading the page. This means that the server cannot find the index.html, probably becuase it sits inside the root folder. Since I cannot set the index document like so:

```
webApp/index.html
```

Is there a way to configure my index.html file without having to take it out of the 'webApp' folder?

Curent Setup:

someBucketName.com --> webApp -- > index.html

Comment: can someone explain why this was downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

The path of index document can be changed by setting.

S3 > (your bucket) > Properties > Enable website hosting > Index Document.

See AWS documentation for details.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html

Update:

You can not include slashes in the index document. The index document must exist directly under the root of the directory.

See also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html

So, I think it needs to be placed in root.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm referring to, the index document cannot be webApp/index.html, and just index.html gives me a 404 error as well

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood. You can not include slashes in the index document. The index document must exist directly under the root of the directory. See also: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/IndexDocumentSupport.html

Comment: @Kode_12 I'm sorry for misunderstanding. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is the index for the `webApp/` path. The index file functions as the index of the path that it resides in. You'll need to copy or move the file to the root of the bucket if you want it to be the index of the root of your site.